# Can I develop website in Wamp and then deploy it on Unix server host?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, unix, iis

Is There a problem if I develop website in Wamp (Windows , Apache , MySQL , PHP) on Windows OS and decided to deploy this site on Unix server Host? Or should I deploy it on IIS Windows Server Host, please help me in this dilemma

Comment: You can certainly develop on Win and deploy on *nix, but there are a few differences between the platforms you need to be aware of, such as case sensitivity of path names. To avoid any surprises during testing, you could use a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox) to run Apache on Linux inside your Windows dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop your site using wamp and deploy on unix server without any issue. But you need to be careful with naming convention of files and database table/field name because window is case insensitive and unix/linux is case sensitive.